# When unit testing, how do I mock a return null from async method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, moq

Normally, I mock my repo like so:

```
var repository = new Mock<ISRepository>();
repository.Setup(r => r.GetMemberAsync(email))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new Member
    {
        FirstName = firstName,
        LastName = lastName
    }));
```

But, in my code, I check to see if the member is not found, i.e. GetMemberAsync returns null.  How do I mock this?

I tried:

```
var repository = new Mock<ISRepository>();
repository.Setup(r => r.GetMemberAsync(email))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>(null));
```

but I get a compile error.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You get a compiler error because you return a task that doesn't match the type the async method returns. You should return `Task<Member>` instead of simply `Task<object>`:

```
repository.Setup(r => r.GetMemberAsync(email)).Returns(Task.FromResult<Member>(null));
```

Comment: Alternatively you can cast `null` to type you want - `Task.FromResult((Member)null)` (not exactly useful in `FromResult` case, but may be handy when type is more complicated).

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked .......repository.Setup(r => r.GetMemberAsync(email)).Returns(Task.FromResult<MyClass>(null));

Answer (score 24):

It is also possible to return the result without using the Task class.

```
repository
    .Setup(r => r.GetMemberAsync(email))
    .ReturnsAsync((Member)null);
```

Comment: 1. Use Async and make sure to TypeCast the NULL;

Answer (score 3):

Old question but you can also do this which I think it cleaner:

Assuming the default value of your object is null you can also use:

```
default(<insert object type here>)
```

e.g.

```
default(Member)
default(List<string>)
etc.
```

Full Example:

```
var myRepo = new Mock<IMyRepo>();
myRepo 
    .Setup(p => p.GetAsync("name"))
    .ReturnsAsync(default(List<string>));
```

Comment: It's less explicit and more verbose than just returning null