# Moq ReturnsAsync using many parameters

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I've been using the `ReturnsAsync` function from Moq with success for a bit, but have bumped into an issue with the following.  I always just return null while I'm adding the parameters to my lambda expression...this time when I got them all added, I get the dreaded "Cannot convert lambda expression to type..."  Is there anything obvious that I got wrong?  The `Setup` method resolves perfectly fine...just not `ReturnsAsync`

Is there a limit to how many parameters that can be defined?  I've tried and noticed that it craps out after the 15th parameter...

```cs
var buildServiceMock = new Mock<IBuildService>();

buildServiceMock
    .Setup(bsm => bsm.QueryBuildsAsync(
        It.IsAny<BuildType>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<DateTime?>(),
        It.IsAny<DateTime?>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<BuildReason?>(),
        It.IsAny<BuildStatus?>(),
        It.IsAny<BuildResult?>(),
        It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
        It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
        It.IsAny<int?>(),
        It.IsAny<int?>(),
        It.IsAny<QueryDeletedOption?>(),
        It.IsAny<BuildQueryOrder?>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<IEnumerable<int>>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((
        BuildType buildType,
        string buildNumber,
        DateTime? minDateTime,
        DateTime? maxDateTime,
        string requestedFor,
        BuildReason? reasonFilter,
        BuildStatus? statusFilter,
        BuildResult? resultFilter,
        IEnumerable<string> tags,
        IEnumerable<string> properties,
        int? top,
        int? maxBuildsPerDefinition,
        QueryDeletedOption? deletedFilter,
        BuildQueryOrder? queryOrder,
        string branchName,
        IEnumerable<int> buildIds,
        string label,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
    {
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356840/7034621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've discovered is the root of my problem is this...

```cs
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TMock, TResult>(this IReturns<TMock, ValueTask<TResult>> mock, Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult> valueFunction) where TMock : class;
```

ReturnsAsync at max will only allow for you to use up to 15 parameters in your lambda expression's signature.

However I only needed the one IEnumerable within my ReturnsAsync delegate method, so I'm good...I was mistaken in that I thought I had to specify a parameter for everyone parameter in the method being mocked up in the "Setup" call...now that I've found you do not need to do that, I'm good to go.  :)